# SQL Server : sort is costing 98% in execution plan

Tags: sql-server

I am using a view like below one:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[VIEW_Test]
AS
    SELECT 
        *,
        [dbo].[fn_Status](id) as ML
    FROM X
```

Sql Function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Status](@id int)
RETURNS [char](1) 
AS 
BEGIN
  DECLARE @res AS char(1)

  IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM a WHERE id = @id AND res = 'FAIL' )
    BEGIN
        SET @res = 'F'
    END
  ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM a WHERE id =@id AND res = 'PASS' )
    BEGIN
        SET @res = 'P'
    END
  ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SET @res = ''
    END

  RETURN (@res)
END
```

and querying it with a CTE as shown below:

```
WITH filtereddata AS
(
     SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a DESC, b DESC) AS Row_Num,
         * 
     FROM 
         [VIEW_Test]
)
SELECT * 
FROM filtereddata 
WHERE Row_Num BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

This CTE takes about 10 seconds to execute, if I remove the function from my view my query is executing in less than 1 second. Please also refer to the actual execution plan:

[image]

Can you please help me optimize this query?

Comment: What does `[dbo].[fn_Status](id)` do? Can you rewrite it to a table valued function?

Comment: Or are you using SQL Server 2019 and the scalar function can therefore be inlined (if it's "inlinable")?

Comment: Sorry its sql 2014 and added sql function too

Comment: Considering that function, then I agree with @HoneyBadger, rewrute that function to an **inline** table value function and retest.

Comment: Using `ROW_NUMBER` for paging will always be slower than using [OFFSET and FETCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#Offset). The server has to sort the data in order to calculate the row number. Try using `select * from view_test order by a desc, b desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY.` The descending sort order will force a `sort` operation though, as all indexes on the table are probably *not* in descending order